# Wordpress Product Detail and catalog

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-development, page-template

I want to have post for every product, some product may have similar feature.For example Size with different Value for each one. and some other product doesn't have Size Feature.
i see [this page](https://www.advantech.com/products/1-2mljw2/pcl-812pg/mod_3ef33953-ade1-4801-aaa1-ad0a6d377e2c) and want to have same template.I design [my custom HTML](http://farazafzar.com/page/) page but i can't use that on WordPress.I need some idea to have page same as up shared link.

Thank you.

Comment: WordPress doesn't have products by default, so if you check with whatever ecommerce plugin you're using, many have ways to set up the templates.

Comment: @WebElaine May you tell me what is the best eCommerce plugin for my propose ? i dont want to have online shop , we need to have product introduction and my you explain me how can i setup my HTML page(as dynamic and editable for other product) ?

Comment: WooCommerce is the only one worth mentioning.  You will need to do some research into what you need.  You can't just post here and expect someone to answer those type of general questions.

Comment: You are right.But I'm looking for ideas that work.I did a lot of research on plugins, and I even realized that it was possible for pages with the same page definition as Single.php to do. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Finally after 4 day i can to do it.I use Visual Composer plugin and add HTML element and paste my HTML code on it.
Note : for CSS and JS i was use CDN address.